# How create signature file to sent web push notification in safari from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, safari, apple-push-notifications, pkcs#7

now I have a server can send push notification to chrome, I want extend for safari too, in apple doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html) but I don't know how make the signature file in nodeJS

> The Signature
>
> The signature is a PKCS #7 detached signature of the
>   manifest file. Sign the manifest file with the private key associated
>   with your web push certificate that you obtained while registering
>   with Apple. In PHP, you can do this with the openssl_pkcs7_sign
>   function. The create_signature function in the attached
>   createPushPackage.php companion file (the link is near the top of the
>   page) shows how you can do this.
>
> If the contents of your push package ever change, you’ll need to
>   recompute your signature.

in the same page apple put a example in php:

```
// Creates a signature of the manifest using the push notification certificate.
function create_signature($package_dir, $cert_path, $cert_password) {
    // Load the push notification certificate
    $pkcs12 = file_get_contents($cert_path);
    $certs = array();
    if(!openssl_pkcs12_read($pkcs12, $certs, $cert_password)) {
        return;
    }

    $signature_path = "$package_dir/signature";

    // Sign the manifest.json file with the private key from the certificate
    $cert_data = openssl_x509_read($certs['cert']);
    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs['pkey'], $cert_password);
    openssl_pkcs7_sign("$package_dir/manifest.json", $signature_path, $cert_data, $private_key, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED);

    // Convert the signature from PEM to DER
    $signature_pem = file_get_contents($signature_path);
    $matches = array();
    if (!preg_match('~Content-Disposition:[^\n]+\s*?([A-Za-z0-9+=/\r\n]+)\s*?-----~', $signature_pem, $matches)) {
        return;
    }
    $signature_der = base64_decode($matches[1]);
    file_put_contents($signature_path, $signature_der);
}
```

somebody know how make the same function in nodeJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok I finally found how to do this, you must first convert the certificate and key to PEM format

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.cer -inform DER -outform PEM -out cert.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -nodes
```

after that, you can sign your manifest with smime module (i use https://github.com/hipush/smime ) and we are ready, we have a signature :) :) :)